# Flutter, pdf package and table component

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

Is it possible to make a nested row using Table.fromTextArray. For example something like this

```
            pw.Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data: const <List<String>>[
              <String>['Date', 'PDF Version', **['First Nested Row','Second Nested Row']**],
              <String>['1993', 'PDF 1.0', 'Acrobat 1'],
              <String>['1994', 'PDF 1.1', 'Acrobat 2'],
              <String>['1996', 'PDF 1.2', 'Acrobat 3'],
              <String>['1999', 'PDF 1.3', 'Acrobat 4'],
              <String>['2001', 'PDF 1.4', 'Acrobat 5'],
              <String>['2003', 'PDF 1.5', 'Acrobat 6'],
              <String>['2005', 'PDF 1.6', 'Acrobat 7'],
              <String>['2006', 'PDF 1.7', 'Acrobat 8'],
              <String>['2008', 'PDF 1.7', 'Acrobat 9'],
              <String>['2009', 'PDF 1.7', 'Acrobat 9.1'],
              <String>['2010', 'PDF 1.7', 'Acrobat X'],
              <String>['2012', 'PDF 1.7', 'Acrobat XI'],
              <String>['2017', 'PDF 2.0', 'Acrobat DC'],
            ]),
```

This doesn't work but would it be possible in some other way?